# TFS 2017 power tool custom field connected to User Story

Tags: tfs, mtm, custom-field-type

Using the power tool I was able to add a new custom field but I want that it take automatically a specific value if present.

Each test case has a "user story" associated but to associate it we have to go in "Tested User Story Section" so I'd like that in the main page appear automatically the ID of the user story.

Sorry for the confusion maybe with the image will be more understandable:

[image: Example]

Someone can advice me of what to introduce in the Visual Studio Power Tool please? because I'm finding different example but none explain how to auto-populate with another dynamic item.

If you are asking me why it's because we want to have the "User Story ID" present in the main page so we know directly at which user story the test case is associated:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the User Story ID as a field. Since a single Test Case can test multiple User Stories this makes little sense anyway.

Have you tried adding Requirement based Suits to Test Professional so that you can see all of the Test Cases under a Story? From a testing perspective it makes lots of sense to look from the Story down to Tests rather than Test up to Stories.

[image]

Although my screenshots are from the Web App the features at the same in MTM. You can add a Requirement Based Test Suite that relates back to the User Story.

[image]

Comment: Hi MrHinsh I really would like to have the ID in the home page but if it's not possible I can manage with the query suit the problem is that I'm not getting a query with "User Story" and "Test Case Associated" I can find just the "user story" or just the "test cases" could you post an example of how is write the query please? or could you give me some extra tips! Thanks so much

Comment: You cant do this with a query. I am selecting one or more User Stories that are added as Requirements-based Suite.

Comment: MrHinsh just one advice, by default the test case status are: "closed","design" and "ready", I'm assuming that I'm able to change them without problem but do you advice me to change or not? because I know that there are other functionality connected to this specific status (for example for testing). if I change the status names the other functionality will still working or I will have to update all the functionality to take the new status?

Comment: It depends on the state that you want? These states are sufficient to monitor Test Cases.

Comment: No, for me this status are good enough but project menage want add some new status the problem is that I don't know how will react MTM. In this moment when I pass a test cases to status "ready" it goes automatically in the test cases ready to be tested but if I change this values I'm afraid that MTM will not work as it should! do you have some extra information or advice of what is better to do?

Comment: You should not change the states. What states so they want?

Comment: they wanted add new status like "to review", "test case rejected" but I don't think that it's a good idea ;)

Comment: sorry to disturb you, but could you see if you can help me in this too? your advice so far were very very good :D tks so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349056/tfs-work-item-type-is-not-allowed-to-be-added-as-a-link

Answer (score 1):

As @MrHinsh mentioned, there is no direct way to get the User Story ID from a field.

From TFS query, it's easy to get the linked User Story, you can select the Work Item and Direct Links in work item query, check the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: sorry to disturb you, but could you see if you can help me in this too? your advice so far were very very good :D tks so much! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42349056/tfs-work-item-type-is-not-allowed-to-be-added-as-a-link